# MySQL Query - Not Equal not showing the correct data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting some wrong results

mt table looks like

```
Name    Mobile     Upload
Aro     xxxxx     /var/www/cms/cvs/
Aro     xxxxx     /var/www/cms/cvs/
Aro     xxxxx     /var/www/cms/cvs/ghgrfr.docx
Aro     xxxxx     /var/www/cms/cvs/
Aro     xxxxx     /var/www/cms/cvs/ghg.docx
```

i want to count only the columns that have .docx so i result should be two but now i am getting all 5 below is my query

```
 SELECT count( `upload` ) AS totalnamecv
    FROM `contact`
    WHERE `upload` <> '/var/www/cms/cvs/'
```

,can anyone tell where i am wrong thanks.

Comment: Have you checked me answer below?

Comment: i checked also i tried my result now is 5 but i want it 2

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.. try running a

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE `upload` <> '/var/www/cms/cvs/' LIMIT 10
```

To check you are filtering out the rows.. I suspect you do not have the exact value you have coded for in the table.

I assume there is a reason you aren't doing `upload = '/var/www/cms/cvs/ghj.docx'`

Comment: @Xavi I'm sorry I don't understand.. please post the results of the query above on your data.

Comment: my result now is 5 but i want it two

Answer (score 0):

I really do not understand what do you want to do. could you show how is you table?

You query is getting "counting all contact which mobile1 is not null, mobile1 is not '' upload is not /var/www/cms/cvs/ (exactly) and contacttype is Person"

So, if you have
contact table
mobile1  upload                     contactype
1        /var/www/cms/cvs/ghj.docx  Person

this query will show it, because '/var/www/cms/cvs/ghj.docx' is not '/var/www/cms/cvs/'

if you want to get something is like (contain) a part, you should use the operator LIKE
you can get more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Update

Maybe you have leading or trailing spaces in that column. Try to clean that column first, like this

```
UPDATE contact
SET upload = TRIM(upload);
```

and then fire your query

---

Change your SQL statement to this

```
SELECT * 
FROM contact
WHERE upload != '/var/www/cms/cvs/' 
  AND contacttype = 'Person'
  AND mobile1 IS NOT NULL 
  AND mobile1 != '';
```

or if you need only the count, to this

```
SELECT COUNT(upload) 
FROM contact
WHERE upload != '/var/www/cms/cvs/' 
  AND contacttype = 'Person'
  AND mobile1 IS NOT NULL 
  AND mobile1 != '';
```

Check the working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3cec/4)